# Vue packages version mismatch: vue@2.6.14 vue-server-renderer@2.7.10

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to compile my app and I am getting the following error

> Vue packages version mismatch: vue@2.6.14 vue-server-renderer@2.7.10

This is because the version of Nuxt I am using (which i need to use) uses vue-server-renderer@2.6.14, but I am not sure whats causing the other conflict

here are my dependencies, is there any way to find out whats causing it, or fix it?

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.5.4",
  "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "0.1.2",
  "@nuxtjs/svg-sprite": "0.5.2",
  "@sendgrid/mail": "6.4.0",
  "body-parser": "1.19.0",
  "chokidar": "3.5.2",
  "clipboard": "2.0.4",
  "compression": "1.7.4",
  "cors": "2.8.5",
  "express": "4.17.1",
  "feed": "4.1.0",
  "gsap": "3.1.1",
  "lazysizes": "5.3.2",
  "lodash": "4.17.21",
  "lru-cache": "5.1.1",
  "moment": "2.24.0",
  "mongoose": "5.9.10",
  "morgan": "1.10.0",
  "nuxt": "2.15.8",
  "pm2": "4.4.0",
  "sanitize-html": "2.5.1",
  "sitemap": "2.2.0",
  "stickyfilljs": "2.1.0",
  "svg4everybody": "2.1.9",
  "swiper": "6.8.4",
  "url-polyfill": "1.1.8",
  "vue-waypoint": "3.2.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.18.10",
  "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.18.9",
  "eslint": "8.23.0",
  "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.3.0",
  "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.7.0",
  "normalize-scss": "7.0.1",
  "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
  "sass": "1.54.7",
  "sass-loader": "10.3.1",
}
```

Full stack trace

> This may cause things to work incorrectly. Make sure to use the same
> version for both.
>
> ```
>  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/index.js:8:9)
>  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
>  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
>  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
>  at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
>  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
>  at Hook._require.Module.require (/usr/src/app/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:101:39)
>  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nuxt/vue-renderer/dist/vue-renderer.js:19:27)
>  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
> ```

Comment: You should get more details in the stacktrace itself. Otherwise, I'm not sure where but I saw an issue related to that one with Nuxt3. Not sure if Nuxt2 is still concerned but maybe try to find a middle ground by down/upgrading some packages to solve the dependecies.

Comment: thanks for the reply i added the full stack trace it comes from cjs which i don't directly reference?

Answer (score 1):

I changed these 3 items and it worked
from

```
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.5.4",
  "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "0.1.2",
  "@nuxtjs/svg-sprite": "0.5.2"
```

to

```
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.10.2",
  "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "1.0.0",
  "@nuxtjs/svg-sprite": "0.4.10"
```

Deleted modules and package-lock file, ran npm install, then it worked